# How to customize add/update record dialog box using jquery-jtable?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-jtable

I used jtable for my application, and I created 8-9 fields. When I try to open the add record dialog box, it is looking like this—header is covering the dialog.
I want to change the dimensions or give some top margin to that dialog box.
Where do I need to change the dimensions of dialog box or where do I need to set top margin for jtable. Please help me out. Output screen attached here.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a late answer but could maybe help someone else.  You can change the dimensions of jQuery-jTable default forms by handling the "formcreated" event:

```js
formCreated: function (event, data) {
  $('#jtable-edit-form').css('height', 'auto');
  $('#jtable-edit-form').css('width', '300px');
  $('input[type=text]').each(function () {
    $(this).css('width', '300px');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following solution:

```
.ui-dialog {
    margin-top: 10px !important;          /*change top margin as you want*/
}
```

Add this into your page. This will override the `ui-dialog` class of `jquery-ui.css`. I am assuming that you are only using it in current page, If you use it in `Site.css` then it will affect on each pages where you have used `ui-dialog` class.

Comment: let me know if this helps you.

Comment: No @abpatil this is not working..
In this I am using 'jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css', 'jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js', 'jquery.jtable.js' and 'jtable.css'..

Comment: I have tested this on my end. Can you tell me where u have added this?

Comment: I have added that in the style tag in head section.

Comment: I have tried to add so many styles to it. Finally I have used 'top: 100px !important;'. Now it is working fine but margin-top is not working. Thank you so much @abpatil..